# Firefox 4 beta 10 is not restoring tabs after crash

Tags: firefox, crash, browser-tabs

Sometimes, my Firefox 4 beta 10 crashes and after restart it does not recover last opened tabs.

In my Firefox 3 it functioned always.

Someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Well, it's called "Beta" so crashes and malfunction are expected. I'd suggest you report them to the Mozilla Bug Tracker

Comment: I know what means "beta", but wanted to solve it, perhaps with another beta, a "more stable one".

Comment: Firefox 4 final has been released, so you might as well update http://www.getfirefox.com

Comment: I downgraded to Firefox 3.6 + ( Tabs on Top + Hide Caption Titlebar Plus).addons => So I have the benefits of FF4 appearance and all add-ons that are compatible with 3.6 but not with 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `General` tab in Preferences, you might want to set `When Firefox Starts` to **Show my Windows and Tabs from Last Time**.  It's very possible that Firefox 4 (which, as bruno077 reminded us, still is in beta) isn't registering the fact that it crashed correctly.

Also, make sure that `browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash` is set to `true` and that `browser.sessionstore.max_resumed_crashes` is greater than or equal to one in `about:config`.

Comment: i've done that, but after RC releases the issue disappeared...